# How to save and restore dynamically created elements on a page?

Tags: nativescript

I am creating different elements dynamically on one of my pages on NativeScript application. Once the app closes or loses focus, on app reload the page is reloaded and the dynamic elements are lost. Is there a way to save the page's state and reload it on page reloading? I know I can save data using application-settings but if I have a lot of dynamically created elements(for example if for every push notification I am creating a new label), the application-settings route becomes cumbersome and elegance of the view may be lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No tool will do this for you.

Within your program, you'll have to save the state of the GUI to settings (application-settings) and then recreate it during loading.

When you have an XML file generated page - the backend is processing to generate the page dynamically. So a page you create from your state will not take that much longer - no elegance should be lost.